# How to set MKMapView activityType?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

`CLLocationManager` has a property called `activityType` where we can set the type of activity that is associated with the location updates.

In my app, I display an `MKMapView` with user location on it so I do not use `CLLocationManager`. Since we can't access `MKMapView`'s location manager, how do we set the `MKMapView`'s `activityType`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't and that's probably intentional. `MKMapView` uses `CoreLocation` to determine your location when you set `showsUserLocation = NO`, which I think is what you're doing. Per the description for that property:

> ... Setting this property to YES causes the map view to use the Core Location framework to find the current location and try to display it on the map. As long as this property is YES, the map view continues to track the user’s location and update it ***periodically***. ...

If you want an `activityType` or `desireAccuracy` level of granularity you have to use the `CoreLocation` API classes. Namely `CLLocationManager.`

As an aside, I would assume that Apple's `MKMapView` is using the significant change location API to manage your location on the map (and possibly AGPS) to conserve battery life, but I could be wrong.

Anyway, I would just create an instance of `CLLocationManager` and set its `activityType`.

Comment: in my app, I have to show the user location and the path he walked. You would create an instance of CLLocationManager to get userLocation and manually draw it on MKMapView by disabling the showsUserLocation? If not, you would have two location update callbacks, one from MKMapView and one from CLLocationManager..

Comment: Yes, that is what I would do. But, like I said, if you want control over CoreLocation you need to create a `CLLocationManager` set its delegate and start listening for `-loationManager:didUpdateLocations:`. This will  give you much better accuracy and control. The second callback from the map's delegate `-mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` should probably be ignored and not implemented.

Comment: Let me clarify and add that you can do what you want to do "show the user location and path he walked" with just `-mapView:didUpdateUserLocation`, however if you want to fine tune the accuracy or the interaction with `CoreLocation` you'll need to use a `CLLocationManager`.

Comment: Ok i see, thanks. That would be what I will be doing.